Как отключить вывод предупреждений на python?
Я работаю с телеграм-ботами, библиотека telebot. Разрабатываю систему, которая позволяет создавать "зеркало" телеграм-бота. Столкнулся с проблемой - если пользователь добавляет бота, который уже используется в другом сервисе, то консоль начинает спамить предупреждением об этом. Бот работает по технологии bot-polling, которая конфликтует с вебхуками.
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first

И это предупреждение никак не отлавливается. Tru - Except их игнорирует.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR) не работает
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") аналогично
Перенаправление вывода тоже
class DevNull:
    def write(self, msg):
        pass
sys.stderr = DevNull()

Я пробовал удалять вебхуки, но другие подключённые сервисы их восстанавливают. Единственный вариант - вручную искать по номеру потока проблемных ботов и удалять их.
Подскажите, как можно отключить вывод таких сообщений или автоматически определить, в каких потоках они происходят. Выполнение кода эти сообщения не прерывают, бот продолжает работать, хотя и получается мешанина ответов из двух сервисов.

Это не предупреждение, это исключение. Ловите именно это исключение там, где оно происходит через try/except.

Для каждого бота нужен отдельный хук.
Хотя у вас это не описано, но подозреваю, что вы используете один хук на оба бота.

Ботов несколько сотен, а веб хуки использую не я, а другие сервисы, к которым их подключают пользователи, которые их добавляют. Я использую bot_polling, так как это не требует покупки домена и сервера. Если ты имеешь в виду, что отлавливать предупреждения нужно на каждом боте в отдельности, то я так и поступаю.

Просто добавь следующий код перед кодом бота:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") 


ChatGPT мне то же самое сказал. Это описано в моём вопросе как один из нерабочих вариантов.

Попробуй тогда этот модуль: https://github.com/polvoazul/shutup

Перенаправь ошибки через консоль
python file.py 2>файл

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
